# How to recover apt-get that was deleted by me?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I was deleting the wine package and somehow `apt-get` was deleted along with wine. Now if I try to use `apt-get` I see message that `apt-get` isn't installed or doesn't exist.

I already installed aptitude, but when I use it I get an error says that I have no driver for `/usr/lib/apt/methods/https`

How can I reinstall apt-get?

Comment: did you try another package manager like synaptic package manager or ubuntu software center to install the apt package?

Comment: nope. it's graphical. i need manager for terminal.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct, Synaptic is the front end for apt, it depends on apt. The same is true for Software Center.

Comment: problem solved. i've collected apt-get from pieces. thx to all who have answered.

Answer (score 6):

`apt-get` is a kind of "frontend" for `dpkg` which is in an ultimate instance, who do all operations. You can easily recover your `apt-get` if you download the package from the repository and install it yourself:

**(this is a illustrative example, I'm using the latest version of apt i386 from precise-updates repository, you should download the one that fits you, for a complete list of versions check: [Ubuntu apt package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apt&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) or [Launchpad apt package list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt). You should check your installed version using `apt-cache policy apt`)**

```
wget http://mirrors.us.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.12_i386.deb http://mirrors.us.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt-transport-https_0.8.16%7Eexp12ubuntu10.12_i386.deb
sudo dpkg --unpack apt_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.12_i386.deb apt-transport-https_0.8.16%7Eexp12ubuntu10.12_i386.deb
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you have your apt-get working again.

> Why not use `--install` instead of separated `--unpack` and `--configure`?

The `--install` switch executes tasks that are not necessary (`prerm`, `preinst`, `postrm`) for recovering apt binaries, and might run into problems later due the sorry state of the installation. For such reason, `--unpack` to get the binaries set in place and `--configure` to restore any lost configuration file are just necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have get apt package from [this link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/apt).
Run

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/.. #As you selected add here
```

In my select package is below:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
```

Then run

```
sudo dpkg --unpack apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope it works